# How to refactor such a big IF-ELSE statement

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have such a big if-else statement. How can I refactor it? Can anyone give some example how to make it more pretty? Thanks!

```
public enum FireState
{
    None,
    NoneToMinor,
    Minor,
    MinorToNone,
    MinorRecovery,
    MinorToMajor,
    Major,
    MajorToNone,
    MajorRecovery
}

private static FireState GetFireState(int previousRespinCount, int currentRespinCount, bool isRecovery)
{
    FireState fire = FireState.None;

    if ((isRecovery || previousRespinCount == 0) && currentRespinCount < MinorJackpotMinRange)
    {
        fire = FireState.None;
    }
    else if (previousRespinCount == 0 &&
        (currentRespinCount >= MinorJackpotMinRange
        && currentRespinCount < MinorJackpotMaxRange))
    {
        fire = FireState.MinorRecovery;
    }
    else if (isRecovery && currentRespinCount >= MinorJackpotMaxRange)
    {
        fire = FireState.MajorRecovery;
    }
    else if (previousRespinCount == (MinorJackpotMinRange - 1)
        && currentRespinCount == MinorJackpotMinRange)
    {
        fire = FireState.NoneToMinor;
    }
    else if (previousRespinCount >= MinorJackpotMinRange
        && (currentRespinCount > 0 && currentRespinCount < MinorJackpotMaxRange))
    {
        fire = FireState.Minor;
    }
    else if ((previousRespinCount >= MinorJackpotMinRange &&
        previousRespinCount < MinorJackpotMaxRange) &&
        currentRespinCount == 0)
    {
        fire = FireState.MinorToNone;
    }
    else if (previousRespinCount == (MinorJackpotMaxRange - 1)
        && currentRespinCount == MinorJackpotMaxRange)
    {
        fire = FireState.MinorToMajor;
    }
    else if (previousRespinCount >= MinorJackpotMaxRange &&
        currentRespinCount >= MinorJackpotMaxRange)
    {
        fire = FireState.Major;
    }
    else if (previousRespinCount >= MinorJackpotMaxRange
        && currentRespinCount == 0)
    {
        fire = FireState.MajorToNone;
    }

    return fire;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Solutions in Java and C# would be different. This looks like C#, not Java, right?

Comment: @TimSchmelter It is Off-Topic. And it would be more appropriate on Code Review. But it being On-Topic there is not itself a valid close reason here.

Answer (score 1):

You start writing unit tests; and use coverage to come to a point where you are sure that you understand all paths through your method. Then you start refactor it, by using the well known methods to do so; and your tests tell you that you don't break anything while going forward.

Finally, you throw away all of this; and you restart with TDD, and you focus to come up with a reasonable design. In your case: you would implement a state machine ... but using polymorphism; instead of cascaded if/else statements.

Long story short: your choices are to do coverage-based refactoring; or if time allows, to re-design the whole component; as your current implementation is simply a state machine in very poor disguise.